# ¿Como conocer la IP de un cliente de una conexion socket?

Tags: c, windows, socket

He hecho un programa y necesito conocer la IP de los clientes que se conectan al servidor que está hecho con sockets. Buscando he encontrado que se debería poder hacer con el sockaddr_in del cliente usando  `inet_ntoa` pero no se porque no me funciona .

Este es mi código:

```
while((doble=accept(sok,(struct sockaddr*)&cliente,0))!=INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("\nse ha recibido una conexion.\n");
        recv(doble,recepcion,sizeof(recepcion),0);
        printf("paso 1:");
        printf(" %s\n%s\n",recepcion,inet_ntoa(cliente.sin_addr));
    }
```

Pero en la consola siempre me aparece esto "paso 1: 5062 1.0.0.0"

Bueno el 5062 cambia según lo que envie el cliente pero la IP siempre me aparece esa y dudo mucho que esté bien XD.

Aclaro que estoy usando winsock2 es decir los sockets de windows y que la función  `inet_ntop` no está en esta librería por lo que no lo puedo hacerlo así.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, suponiendo que está utilizando IPV4, haga lo siguiente:

```
struct sockaddr_in* pV4Addr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&client_addr;
struct in_addr ipAddr = pV4Addr->sin_addr;
```

Si luego desea la dirección IP como una cadena, haga lo siguiente:

```
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop( AF_INET, &ipAddr, str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN );
```

IPV6 también es bastante fácil ...

```
struct sockaddr_in6* pV6Addr = (struct sockaddr_in6*)&client_addr;
struct in6_addr ipAddr       = pV6Addr->sin6_addr;
```

y obtener una cadena es casi idéntico a IPV4

```
char str[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop( AF_INET6, &ipAddr, str, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN );
```

Comment: Se me ha olvidado ponerlo en la pregunta aunque lo he puesto en las etiquetas pero estoy haciendo el programa con los sockets de windows es decir con la librería winsock2. Y en esta librería la funcion inet_ntop no existe creo que el equivalente es inet_ntoa que es lo que he usado en el ejemplo pero no funciona XD